# TypeScript compiler in Gulp says it cannot find @angular modules but compiles fine

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp

I'm getting a lot of "false" errors when my `gulp` task compiles my typescript. Here's the relevant `gulp task`:

```
var tsProject = typescript.createProject('tsconfig.json', {noResolve: true});

gulp.task('build-ts', function() {
    gulp.src(appDev + '**/*.ts')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(typescript(tsProject))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        //.pipe(jsuglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(appProd));
    gulp.src(appDev + '**/*.+(html|css)')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(appProd));
});
```

And these are the errors I get:

```
[09:38:52] Starting 'default'...
[09:38:52] Finished 'default' after 8.88 ms
ng/app.component.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
ng/app.component.ts(5,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.
ng/app.module.ts(1,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
ng/app.module.ts(2,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser'.
ng/app.module.ts(3,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/common'.
[...]
[09:38:53] TypeScript: 27 semantic errors
[09:38:53] TypeScript: emit succeeded (with errors)
[BS] Proxying: http://0.0.0.0:5000
```

My tree structure looks like this (simplified):

```
.
├── gulpfile.js
├── ng
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
├── typings.json
└── web
```

All the modules that the Typescript compiler fails to find are actually in `node_modules` and my final application works fine despite all the errors.

This is my `tsconfig.js`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "./app"
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "./app/**/*.ts",
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ],
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": true
  }
}
```

How can I get rid of these "false positive" errors.

Comment: I think there is a problem with the files passed to the typescript compilation. On the one hand, you pass your `appDev` files and set `noResolve`. On the other hand you have a different config in your `tsconfig`. (Caution: files and exclude don't work together and also your tsconfig isn't rewritten by gulp!) If you have problems with the resolution of typings, you can add the `traceResolution` flag to the typescript compiler invocation. That should give you some hints. see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Module%20Resolution.md#tracing-module-resolution.

Comment: You should also have a look at the `noResolve` option you are passing. This causes to not follow any imports to files that are not passed to the TypeScript compiler. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Module%20Resolution.md#using---noresolve. I'd suggest to not `gulp.src` but either start from the `tsproject` as source of truth: https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript#using-tsconfigjson

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the **gulp.js** file the line

```
var tsProject = typescript.createProject('tsconfig.json', {noExternalResolve: true, noResolve: true});
```

should be

```
var tsProject = typescript.createProject('tsconfig.json');
```

As we want to load external typings.

And also you need to load the typings in the **main.ts** file on the top :

```
/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />
```

I did clone your project and it compiles without warnings after this.

Comment: funnily enough I tried those two things independently before. thanks!

Comment: I told you before that's because of typings, but didn't knew your entire config :)

Comment: Typings should not be included with reference but directly in tsconfig or your build chain.